# Can I only call static functions from a form to another?

Tags: c#

I have 2 forms connected to a database, `LoadDocument` form and a `Fom1` that is the primary form. In `LoadDocument` I get document names out of my database, and when I close `LoadDocument` I send the document id to `Form1` so I can retrieve its content there.

The only problem is that if i make a function in `Form1`, called `public void showContent()` my `LoadDocument` can't call it because it's not static, and if I make it static, I get problems creating `radioButtons`.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public void showTasks()
    {
        radioButtons = new RadioButton[numberOfTasks];
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTasks; ++i)
        {
            radioButtons[i] = new RadioButton();
            radioButtons[i].Text = "Task " + (i+1);
            radioButtons[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(
                10, 10 + i * 20);
            groupBox1.Controls.Add(radioButtons[i]);
            radioButtons[i].Click += new EventHandler(this.radioButtons_Click);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can call this function from `LoadDocument` without making it static? Do I have to make `LoadDocument` dynamic, and in that case how?

EDIT: I guess this piece of code would be quite relevant:

```
    private LoadDocument m_form1;
    private bool m_underConstruction = false;
    private void ShowLoadDocument()
    {
        if (m_underConstruction)
        {
            // We're about to show it anyway
            return;
        }
        m_underConstruction = true;
        try
        {
            if (m_form1 == null)
            {
                m_form1 = new LoadDocument();
                // m_form1.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(m_form1_FormClosed);
                m_form1.Show();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            m_underConstruction = false;
        }
        m_form1.BringToFront();
        m_form1.Activate();
    }
```

Comment: the interesting part in your code is the code that invokes showTasks(). if from the LoadDocument form you call a function of an -instance- of Form1, there shouldn't be a problem, but i guess you're calling it as a static method of Form1.

Comment: Calling it from a button on the LoadDocument form
        private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1.activeDocumentId = documentId;
            // Form1.showTasks();
            this.Close();
        }

Comment: The problem is your architecture.  Why are forms diddling with each other's contents anyways?  You should be updating a common model of some sort that each form reflects.  You shouldn't *need* to be calling any methods on the other form.

Comment: @Raptor: that's the problem... your'e not calling an instance of a Form1 form, but a method in the class Form1 (which is by definition supposed to be static)

Comment: Siride would you care to explain that a little more? I'm trying to make Form1 my "base" or something. (my english is lacking here sorry) Should i have most of it in program.cs instead or what are you reffering to?

Comment: @Raptor: you can create additional classes.  These classes can contain data and logic for your program and they will be used by the UI classes as needed.  Perhaps you should read about OO design principles.  Otherwise, if you try to do anything halfway complicated using the model you are using now, you will be in for a world of pain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about the control flow and the co-existence of the two forms, but you could pass the instance of Form1 to LoadDocument and call the method directly on that object. Like:

```
public class LoadDocument : Form {

    private Form1 form1;
    public LoadDocument(Form1 form1) {
        this.form1 = form1;
    }

    // later

    public void Method() {
        form1.showTasks();
    }
}


public class Form1 : Form {

     public void SomeMethod() {              
        LoadDocument doc = new LoadDocument(this);
        doc.Show();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `showContent` method on an instance of `Form1`.

I understand that the `LoadDocument` form is created from `Form1`. Pass the instance of `Form1` to the `LoadDocument` constructor. That way, you'll be able to do `form1WhoCreatedMe.ShowContent()` somewhere in `LoadDocument`.

The [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) keyword won't help you there. `dynamic` is **not** the contrary of [`static`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx).

Comment: how so i make an instance of my Form?

Comment: @Raptor: Exactly like demonstrated in the answer written by **Tudor**.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make it static, but you need to have a reference to `Form1` to call it. You can pass this reference to the constructor of `LoadDocument` when you create it:

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    ...

        LoadDocument loadDocument = new LoadDocument(this);
        loadDocument.ShowDialog();

    ...
}

public class LoadDocument : Form
{
    private readonly Form1 _form1;

    public LoadDocument(Form1 form1)
    {
        _form1 = form1;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    ...


         _form1.showTasks();

    ...
}
```